# Sanitize user uploaded CSS in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sanitization

After doing an extensive research on the internet, I have not found anything suitable that will help me remove any dangerous things in CSS files when uploaded in NodeJS.

Does anyone know one that could do this?

Comment: You could try to “parse” CSS to verify that the syntax is correct and error free, something like code formatters like Prettier. But that would be a lot of work.

Comment: @GabrielMaizo I think the syntax can be correct, while still presenting XSS attacks